# NHibernate configuration: Configure(pathToXml) vs AddXmlFile(pathToXml)?

Tags: nhibernate, nhibernate-configuration

What's the difference between

[`Configuration.Configure(string)`](http://mausch.github.com/nhibernate-3.2.0GA/html/40af7584-6883-8989-2b39-162c32df64c4.htm)`//Configure NHibernate using the file specified.`

and

[`Configuration.AddXmlFile(string)`](http://mausch.github.com/nhibernate-3.2.0GA/html/7af5b9da-0969-5f42-d206-771bfe74cd5e.htm)`//Read mappings from a particular XML file.`

?

It looks like the latter's functionality is a subset of the former's, but does anyone care to elaborate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first one is to configure dialect, driver and other configurations properties.

The second is used if you want to append an additional XML mapping (HBM) file to an existing configuration object.

For example, create a Configuration using FluentNHibernate then append a classic XML mapping  (when migrating legacy NH application to FNH, for example).

Comment: While the _first_ one is to configure dialect, driver and other configurations properties.